# Laravel show posts by category

Tags: php, laravel, categories

I'm struggling with this functionality in Laravel 5.5 for a week, so guys please help me to solve this issue.

In my database I have these tables:

categories - id, created_at, updated_at

categories_translations id, category_id, locale, user_id, name, slug, created_at, updated_at

teams - id, created_at, updated_at

teams_translations - id, team_id, locale, title, slug, image, body, created_at, updated_at

I'm using Laravel translatable 3rd-party from here:
https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable

So far I've created relationship successfully with these tables and in my admin section I'm showing created teams with related categories.
Also on frontpage I'm showing all teams in one page list. When I click on specific team, it shows the team page. That's great.

I'm struggling with showing teams by categories.

So, this is my code.

Category model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Dimsav\Translatable\Translatable;

class Category extends Model
{
    use Translatable;

    public $translatedAttributes = ['name', 'slug', 'status', 'user_id', 'image', 'locale'];

    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Team::class);
    } 
}
```

CategoryTranslation model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CategoryTranslation extends Model
{
  use Sluggable;

  protected $touches = ['category'];
  public $timestamps = false;

  /**
   * Return the sluggable configuration array for this model.
   *
   * @return array
   */
  public function sluggable()
  {
      return [
          'slug' => [
              'source' => 'name',
              'onUpdate' => true
          ]
      ];
  }

  public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
  }
}
```

Team model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Dimsav\Translatable\Translatable;

class Team extends Model
{
    use Translatable;

    public $translatedAttributes = ['title', 'slug', 'body', 'status', 'user_id', 'image', 'category_id', 'locale'];

    public function category() {
       return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

TeamTranslation model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TeamTranslation extends Model
{
    use Sluggable;

    protected $touches = ['team'];
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * Return the sluggable configuration array for this model.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function sluggable()
    {
        return [
            'slug' => [
                'source' => 'title',
                'onUpdate' => true,
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function team() {
      return $this->belongsTo(Team::class);
    }
}
```

Part of my route:

```
Route::get('/team/category/{category}', ['uses' => 'TeamController@teamCategory', 'as' => 'teamCategory']);
```

Part of my TeamController:

```
public function teamCategory(Category $category) {

  return $category;
}
```

And here is my view:

```
@extends('layouts.frontend')

@section('title', __('t.team'))

@section('content')
  <div class="main team-list">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul>
          @foreach($categories as $category)
            <li><a href="{{ route('teamCategory', $category->slug) }}">{{ $category->name }}</a></li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        @foreach($teams as $team)
          @if($team->status == 1)
            <div class="row">
              <div class="image">
                <a href="{{ route('team.team', $team->slug) }}"><img width="120" src="{{ Storage::url($team->image) }}" ></a>
              </div>
              <div class="title">
                {{ $team->title }}
              </div>
              <div class="body">
                {!! str_limit($team->body, 300) !!}
              </div>
              <div class="category">
                  {{ $team->category ? $team->category->name : 'No category' }}
              </div>
              <a class="more">More</a>
            </div>
          @endif
        @endforeach
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
@endsection
```

For a example I have a category name php, so in the view when I click on the category link, it goes to this url: mywebsite.com/en/team/category/php and it shows:

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
```

I've tried to add this method in the Category model:

```
public function getRouteKeyName() {
      return 'slug';
    }
```

and it shows:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'slug' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `categories` where `slug` = php limit 1)
```

Later I've tried with this too:

```
public function getRouteKeyName() {
          return 'name';
        }
```

but it shows this:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `categories` where `name` = php limit 1)
```

Anyone help?

EDIT:

I've tried Nikola's answer like this:

CategoryTranslation model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CategoryTranslation extends Model
{
  use Sluggable;

  protected $touches = ['category'];
  public $timestamps = false;

  /**
   * Return the sluggable configuration array for this model.
   *
   * @return array
   */
  public function sluggable()
  {
      return [
          'slug' => [
              'source' => 'category.slug',
              'onUpdate' => true
          ]
      ];
  }

  public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
  }
}
```

TeamTranslation model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TeamTranslation extends Model
{
    use Sluggable;

    protected $touches = ['team'];
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * Return the sluggable configuration array for this model.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function sluggable()
    {
        return [
            'slug' => [
                'source' => 'team.slug',
                'onUpdate' => true,
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function team() {
      return $this->belongsTo(Team::class);
    }
}
```

but it shows the same error.

Comment: Can you give us html too?

Comment: Hi, Nikola. I've added the view.

Comment: Based off of their official docs, `source` represents the actual attribute you are using to store the slug, and it can be used with a dot notation, which means it supports relationships, so since you have relationships in your translate models, `category.slug` and `team.slug` are valid sources

Answer (score 0):

Try with updating your 2 sluggable methods in your translate classes to these:

**CategoryTranslation.php**

```
/**
 * Return the sluggable configuration array for this model.
 *
 * @return array
 */
  public function sluggable()
  {
    return [
        'slug' => [
            'source' => 'category.slug',
            'onUpdate' => true
        ]
    ];
  }
```

**TeamTranslation.php**

```
/**
 * Return the sluggable configuration array for this model.
 *
 * @return array
 */
  public function sluggable()
  {
    return [
        'slug' => [
            'source' => 'team.slug',
            'onUpdate' => true
        ]
    ];
  }
```

The above code is based on [official docs](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable#configuration) and should be working with your implementation

**EDIT**: I've just noticed you are fetching the wrong entity from your controller, try using this code instead

```
public function teamCategory(CategoryTranslation $category) {

  return $category;
}
```

Comment: I've tried that too, Nikola, but it has the same error.

Comment: @user2519032 check my updated answer and correct the code inside of your controller

Comment: By using that 3rd part translatable package, there's no need to use Translation tables in controller, even tough I've tried that too and the error is the same.

Comment: Can you create a plunker and include your migration files there @user2519032?

Comment: I'm afraid it won't help by including the migration files. The problem is related with the 3rd party Laravel translatable. As I read, there's an option by using route inside the boot method from the AppServiceProvider. I'm getting json results successfully, but there's other issue related with editing the admin area categories..now I'm searching for a better solution...it become way too complicated...

Comment: I would recommend you fallback to the standard slug system resolved internally by laravel, sorry we couldn't be of more help

Comment: Unfortunately, the standard Laravel slug system is way back and it's not a good example when you work with Eloquent. I'll continue to search for a solution and test. When I find a solution, I will post it here. Thanks anyway, Nikola!